# Show two symbols for each legend label

Tags: r, plot, symbols, data-visualization, legend

Using `pch` I can plot any symbol and assign any label to in the legend. But how can I plot two symbols for each legend label? For example, in the plot below, I would like to have ■ ▲ ● paired with red versions of those so I have only three labels 'a', 'b', 'c' displayed in the legend, for those six symbols. At the moment, it seems that basic plot legend allows me to only plot one symbol for each label:

```
plot(rnorm(50),pch=c(15:17),col=1:2)
legend('topleft',pch=c(15:17),col=1:2,legend=c("a","b","c"),cex=1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: What prevent you from constructing a legend yourself with a combination of `points()` and `text()`? (or would this be an 'acceptable' solution?) Another idea would be to use `ggplot2` with a `discrete` and `color` scale.

Comment: @chl: Your first point - I thought that more robust/automatic solution would be possible. Your second point - I honestly dislike ggplot2, because it adds to much chartjunk by default, so I avoid it. Maybe you have similar idea for lattice/grid?

Comment: Hmm.  I wonder if ggplot2 themes can be tweaked to make you happier.  What do you consider chartjunky other than the backgrounds and grid lines? Although I think the lattice solution provided by @Josh O'Brien below should suit you nicely.

Comment: @BenBolker: I like simplicity of basic plots and how effortless and minimalistic it is to tweak them to get what you want. I know you can get the same state with ggplot2 but I always found it annoying that things you mentioned (background, grid) plus distances between labels, scales, sizes of fonts need yet another line to make it right. Plus I have lots of plots done in basic graphics so consistency always suffer when I am using ggplot2. Saying that, solutions like package [uniplot](http://crantastic.org/packages/uniPlot) are great for unification of design...

Comment: I have to ask: is this really the best way to present data? You still need to present the meaning of different colors for each of "a" "b" "c", so why not use non-filled characters next to abc in the legend, followed there or elsewhere with an explanation of the difference between black and red.

Comment: This is absolutely valid question @Carl, and I have to admit that empty point was my initial strategy. But I have quite problematic collaborator who has different views on that, and for this person the legend should EXACTLY represent the points on the plot. My other choice would be to have separate legends for each condition. Bugger...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't too hard with `lattice`, as its `key =` argument takes an arbitrary number of columns to be included in the legend.

```
library(lattice)

myPCH <- 15:17
Data  <- rnorm(50)
Index <- seq(length(Data))

xyplot(Data ~ Index, 
       pch = myPCH, col=1:2,
       key = list(space = "right", adj=1,
                  text = list(c("a", "b", "c"), cex=1.5),
                  points = list(pch = myPCH),
                  points = list(pch = myPCH,col=2)))
```

I don't know off the top of my head how to include the legend inside the plotting area, but with this kind of plot it seems better to have it outside anyway. (**Edit:** @chl in comments kindly points out a couple of ways to do this. To plot the key in the lower-left of the figure, for instance, replace `space = "right"` in the above with either `corner = c(0,0)` or `x = 0, y=0.2`)

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks @Josh (again)! I need to explore lattice more. You also solved my other problem that is changing size of legend symbols without changing the size of the font:-)

Comment: Sweet. Like you, for whatever reason, I also happen to prefer the cleaner look of lattice's graphical defaults (though I'm sure those could be tweaked easily enough). In ggplot's favor, it's got more intuitive syntax, a large fan (and thus support) base here on SO, and seems to be under much more active development. I'm starting to think I may end up taking that plunge one of these days...

Comment: (+1) Nice response. (btw, you can alter legend location using `corner` or `x=, y=`; e.g., `key=list(x=.1, y=.9, adj=1, ...` will put the legend inside the plotting region.)

Comment: @chl -- Thanks! I've added that info to the answer above. You've convinced me I need, once and for all, to just print out the `?xyplot` documentation, and read it straight through from top to bottom!

Comment: I don't know @Josh, I am not convinced (yet). Every time I see something done with ggplot2, Tufte and Cleveland scream, and a kitten dies. Even manuals for ggplot2 have [ugly examples](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Graph-Panel-Attributes). This can be due to (a) people not knowing how to make graphs look nice (b) ggplot2 being more intuitive, more developed, BUT lacking the proper coordination of visual elements by default.

Comment: @GeekOnAcid -- What can I say? The images at that link do make your case quite well. To be fair, I've concluded that Hadley et al. just have a radically different aesthetic than I do; I've just been surprised by how many others seem to *enthusiastically* share it. I've often idly wished for some plugin that would support lattice-like plots in ggplot2(), but the closest I've come is finding the functions `ggplot2like()` and `ggplot2like.opts()` in the `latticeExtra()` package -- which take things in precisely the wrong direction!

Answer (score 5):

Like chl pointed out, it is also possible to build a customized legend. The function 'legend' invisibly returns boundaries of the legend box as well as the coordinates of the legend text. One could plot the legend text without symbols, and then add the symbols manually with 'points' to the returned coordinates. This would not require any additional graphics packages:

```
plot(rnorm(50), pch=c(15:17), col=1:2)
# Plot legend text, inset could be used to shift legend text to the right
pos <- legend('topleft', legend=c("a","b","c"), cex=1.5)
# Plot symbols in two columns, shifted to the left by 3 and 1 respectively
points(x=rep(pos$text$x, times=2) - c(3,1), 
    y=rep(pos$text$y, times=2), 
    pch=rep(c(15:17), times=2), col=rep(1:2, times=3))
```

[image: The image produced by the code]